# Contradictory documentation on sysctlbyname return value

Tags: c, macos

The man pages sysctl(3) state that `sysctlbyname` and the other mentioned functions return either 0 in case of success or -1 and set `errno`. But the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1387446-sysctlbyname/)  (for objective C) for `sysctlbyname` says the following about the the return values:

> Return value
>
> 0 on success, or an error code that indicates a problem occurred. Possible error codes include EFAULT, EINVAL, ENOMEM, ENOTDIR, EISDIR, ENOENT, and EPERM.

So which is it, 0/-1 & errno or error code returned directly? Or does it return something different in objective C than the C function mentioned in the man pages? But even the provided example in Apple's documentation only checks for return value -1 and then uses `errno` to log the error. Seems to me that Apple's documentation is wrong or at least unclear.

Comment: Considering that the example in the Apple documentation also uses `-1` as error return, I would argue that it's badly phrased. It returns `-1` on error, and the "possible error codes" are stored as usual in `errno`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685480) by Apple, the documentation for the KPI version of sysctlbyname is confusing. It behaves as expected like the user space version described in the man pages. It returns 0 on success or -1 if an error occurs and sets `errno`.